# Buttons are not visible in winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, controls

We have a wierd issue here.
We have a win-form application. The application has a tabbed form with few textboxs, combo boxes and 3 bottons. The application runs fine in most machines but in 1 machine the buttons are not visible .
Rest all are working fine. Just the buttons are invisible. But the button is present as Iam able to fire the event using tab and enter.
We have checked the log.but cannot find any exceptions logged.
We have checked various resolution but didnt help.

Any help ?

Buttons are at the bottom of the screen just above the taksbar. Taskbar is visible.
We have checked the dotnet frame work .Its fine
Issue is found in a Vista Machine

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What OS do those machines have? What if anything is different about those machines? Framework version etc...

Comment: Can you provide more details? For example, what are the "few" machines specs (OS, .Net version, etc)? What are the specs for the machines it works on? Can you provide source code for how the buttons are added and contained within the WinForm? More details the better.  Otherwise people can only make guesses.

Comment: Sorry about that..Issue is found in only 1 machine..That is Vista..We have checked the dotnet frame works also.. Issue is found in a HP Elite Book 8400 P

Comment: Maybe the DPI settings on the machine are not standard? see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/04/15/why-does-a-high-dpi-setting-make-my-application-look-fuzzy-and-have-clipped-text.aspx

Comment: Does the button work if you click the area where it's supposed to be? Could it be that the colors of the button are the same as the background?

Comment: Iam unable to add more information because issue found in our distant clients machine.

Comment: @Ananth It is best to EDIT your answer to provide any new information. Other than that based on what you have provide you can only take the guesses that are provided, but you really need to start digging into every possible difference this laptop has.  I like Simon Mourier suggestion since you already checked resolution.

Comment: @msergeant  Buttons do work where it is supposed to be. It is not the colors because I have an image on each buttons.. Buttons are at the bottom of the screen just above the taksbar. Taskbar is visible.

Comment: Silly question: have you tried resizing the form?

Comment: What's the height of the screen versus the height of the application?

Comment: Are all buttons invisible? What happens if you add a new button at the top of the window? This test can rule out DPI and layout problems. If you're drawing an image on the buttons, maybe try to change their appearance to just a plain background color, to rule out rendering issues.

Comment: Setting the WrapContents to false on the FlowLayouPanel we were using, fixed a very similar issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess would be that the one machine has a different DPI setting. Perhaps it's pushing the buttons more downwards than they're supposed to be and that causes the buttons to disappear beneath the border of the form?

Also, I'd check the buttons' Anchor property to see where they're anchored to and that they're not moved around by weird window size to behind something else.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the buttons are not included in a tab which is on top of the buttons. Try making tabs (or various other controls) invisible to make sure the buttons not being obscured.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the WrapContents to false on the FlowLayouPanel we were using, fixed a very similar issue. 
The Buttons were near the bottom edge of the dialog box and would disappear in certain monitors resolutions. I think the WrapContents=false clips the buttons than completely removing them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had login Panel where the height of it was depending on Main Form size, For example the height was Form size * 0.1.

The fix was to make the Login Panel resize its size depending on its components by setting loginPanel.AutoSize = true;